# Is there a way to block css elements based on wildcard rules?

Tags: css, adblock

The Guardian has a very annoying yellow banner.

[image]

As you can see it's given a random name every time. Always css-6 random characters.

How can I write a ublock origin rule that will catch it?

Had a look here
https://www.reddit.com/r/ublock/comments/2zam3w/wildcards_in_element_hiding_rules/

and here
https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings

And tried a lot of things, but am just really flapping around in the dark.

Obvious things like css-* don't work.r

Comment: By a random name, do you mean an element with a name attribute with a value of css-<6 character long code>?

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I mean - exactly 6 random characters. I couldn't work out how to do that from the dupe linked

Comment: Your question is already answered as linked at the top. Hope that'll be useful.

Comment: Well, no, it is not useful - as I mentioned I'd read the question of which this has been marked duplicate, and still didn't understand what I needed to do...